# Convert angular factory to angular es6 service

Tags: angularjs, ecmascript-6, angular-services

I have this factory:

```
.factory('FeedLoad', function ($resource) {
    return $resource('http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/load', {}, {
        fetch: { method: 'JSONP', params: {v: '1.0', callback: 'JSON_CALLBACK'} }
    });
})
```

The factory is called this way:

```
FeedLoad.fetch({
    q: data.responseData.url
}, {}, function (data) { //lookup title
    if (data.responseStatus != 200) {
        return;
    }

    $scope.feed.title = data.responseData.feed.title;
});
```

I tried this way to convert it to an angular ES6 service:

```js
class FeedParserService {
  constructor($resource) {
    'ngInject';

    RESOURCE.set(this, $resource);
  }
  feedLoad(){
    return RESOURCE.get(this)('http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/lookup', {}, {
        fetch: { method: 'JSONP', params: {v: '1.0', callback: 'JSON_CALLBACK'} }
    });
  }
}
```

And I'm trying to call it this way:

```js
data = feedParserService.feedLoad().fetch({
  q: this.dataSet[i].szUrl;
}, {}, function(data){

});
```

But it doesn't seem to work. I could use a hand please.

Comment: Just to get this out of the way: is it a mixup between `feedCheck` and `feedLoad`?

Comment: yeah sorry i just correct it. My service has two methods  i just put one in this example and i took the wrong one.

Comment: yeah, I figured it'd probably be something like that, but you never know.

Comment: "But it doesn't seem to work".  Please add more detail.  What is the intended result, and the result you are actually receiving?

Comment: RESOURCE is just a weakmap form es6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So for this use case you should be using a factory rather than a service.

In most cases where the `factory` method is used, it actually should use the `service` method and be a `class` in ES6. This case is the exception. You need to register a factory method that calls the `$resouce factory`.

In ES6 and (and mostly ES5 if you replace import with require) it should look something like this:

```
import {app} from '../app';    

feedLoadFactory.$inject = ['$resource'];
feedLoadFactory($resource) {

    return 
        $resource('http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/load', 
            {}, {
               fetch: { 
                   method: 'JSONP', 
                   params: {v: '1.0', callback: 'JSON_CALLBACK'} 
               }
        });
}

app.factory('feedLoad', feelLoadFactory);
```

Then you can inject it as `feedLoad` and use it as `feedLoad.fetch...`

Comment: I will try that in few hours and keep you update. Thx for the answer man !